# div on an image at the bottom right corner

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a div on the bottom right corner of an image like the one which YouTube has.

[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UF33.png)

what I have is this

[what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X6Pq.png)

I tried but what I was getting is empty div inside the thumbnail div
my code (**without my attempts**):

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

.description {
  display: block;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
}


/**************DON'T EDIT HERE IT'S NOT NECESSARY*************/


/******GRID******/

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /*gap*/
}


/* For mobile phones and Extra small screens: */

.col-sm-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-sm-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-sm-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-sm-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-sm-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.col-sm-visible {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-md-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-lg-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xlg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xlg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xlg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xlg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-xl-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}

.icon {
  width: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 2px;
  opacity: 90%;
}

.margin-0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <a class="" href="">
      <div class="model">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <div>

          </div>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/900" alt="thumbnail">
          <div>
            <p>143 pics</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">

          <span class="title">The model name </span>
          <div class="description">
            <span class="country">Country </span> |
            <span class="date">3 days</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the `<div><p>143 pics</p></div>` goes into the bottom corner of the picture the same that youtube has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set these

```
.thumbnail{
  position: relative;
}
.thumbnail p{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #00000082;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have that using this code.

```css
.card {
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.info {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50px;
}

.description {
  display: block;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.thumbnail {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
}

.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
}
.thumbnail div { padding: 5px 6px 3px; position: absolute; right: 5px; bottom: 5px; z-index: 1; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); color: #fff; }
.thumbnail div p { margin: 0; }
/**************DON'T EDIT HERE IT'S NOT NECESSARY*************/


/******GRID******/

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
  /*gap*/
}


/* For mobile phones and Extra small screens: */

.col-sm-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}

.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

.col-sm-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}

.col-sm-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

.col-sm-9 {
  width: 75%;
}

.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}

.col-sm-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}

.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-sm-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.col-sm-visible {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  /* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-md-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-lg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-lg-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}


/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-xlg-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-xlg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-xlg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-xlg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-xlg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-xlg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-xl-hidden {
    display: none;
  }
  .col-xl-visible {
    display: block;
  }
}

.icon {
  width: 18px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  margin: 2px;
  opacity: 90%;
}

.margin-0 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.padding-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="card">
    <a class="" href="">
      <div class="model">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/900" alt="thumbnail">
          <div>
            <p>143 pics</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">

          <span class="title">The model name </span>
          <div class="description">
            <span class="country">Country </span> |
            <span class="date">3 days</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container
{
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    position:relative;
}

#image
{    
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
#text
{
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;    
    color:white;
    font-size:14px;
    right:10px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="image" src="http://www.noao.edu/image_gallery/images/d4/androa.jpg"/>
    <p id="text">
        Hello World!
    </p>
</div>
```